# disable a button control in datagridview cell based on content in same cell

Tags: asp.net, datagridview, databound

I have a situation where a cell has databound text and a control in it.based on the text in need to enable or disable a cell. text is databound. I tried in ondatadound_row event but there data is not available.
plz help me asap

Comment: Is this question about asp.net(web application) or WinForms(Windows application)? Are you working in vb.net or c#?